# Problem Drag-able list items.[WebOS 3.0 ENYO]

Tags: webos, enyo

i 'mstuck in one problem Drag-able list items.... i want to arrange my list with drag option 
I'm building an app that makes heavy use of lists and I can't seem to find any way to make list items re-orderable by drag and drop. Am I missing something or is there simply no way to do this?

suppose
1.lorem ipsum aa
2.lorem ipsum bb
3.lorem ipsum cc
4.lorem ipsum rr
5.lorem ipsum ee

drag 2nd list item and set it to 4th ... i know this is easily possible in iphone but is there any option in enyo?
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1.0 release, the Enyo framework doesn't have reorderable lists.

Comment: I think it should be, is there any alternative or code in GIT link plz

Answer (score 2):

Somebody on the WebOs development forums actually created a reorder-able list with enyo and released the code. See - https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15850